# Get and alert the error message of textfield in Extjs

Tags: validation, extjs

I use extjs2.x created a form:

```
Ext.QuickTips.init();
Ext.form.Field.prototype.msgTarget = 'side';    

var form = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
    items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield',
         xtype: 'textfield',
         name: 'name',
         anchor: '95%',
         fieldLabel: '<span style="color:red">*</span> Name',
         allowBlank: false,
         blankText: 'Name should not be null'
    }]
});
```

When I leave the field blank and submit the form, it will have a red '!' on the right side, and if I move the cursor on it, it will show a message "Name should not be null".

But what I want is to alert it. How to get the current error message of the first invalid field and alart it? I checked the API doc and searched on google, but not lucky.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you are:

```
form.items.each(function(x) {
    if (x.validate === undefined) {
        return;
    }
    x.validate();
    alert(x.getActiveError());
});
```

This works in Ext 4.0 and 3.4 at least. I don't have older version to check it.

Comment: Finally I used some stupid methods to show the error message, but your solution worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Please check [this](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?82354-Get-invalid-fields-from-tabbed-form) solution posted by Animal. It is very nice and powerful code (can do much more you need, but will give you ideas).
There are versions for Extjs 3.x and 4.x.